# Can't resolve all parameters for service provider?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

There is a service that I use as provider in each components:

```
export class LayersSemanticService {
    constructor(
    private nMapLibrary: MapLibraryService,
    private linkService: LinkService
  ) {
  }
}
```

Using as instance:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-intersection-layer-component",
  templateUrl: "./intersection-layer-component.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./intersection-layer-component.component.scss"],
  providers: [LayersSemanticService]
})
```

Problem is that I get this eror:

```
compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for LayersSemanticService: (?, ?).
```

It can be solve by using service as root service, but I need seperate instance of service.

Comment: How are `MapLibraryService` and `LinkService` configured as providers? Are they provided in root?

Comment: `MapLibraryService` as   `providedIn: "root"` and `LinkService` also is `providedIn: "root`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you are declaring`LayersSemanticService` in your component `providers`, you still need to mark the service as `@Injectable()`.

```js
@Injectable()
export class LayersSemanticService {
    constructor(
    private nMapLibrary: MapLibraryService,
    private linkService: LinkService
  ) {
  }
}
```

From [the docs](https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable), `@Injectable` is a:

> Decorator that marks a class as available to be provided and injected as a dependency.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aaxmvr

Comment: Problem is that one instance service refers to another, how to solve it? When I call method from service: `let data = getObjectSemantic(semantic: LayerItemGeneric): ObjectInformationCustom {}` and call the same method in another component it rewrites result let data;

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Do you want an instance per component or not?

Comment: Yes, but now it works as one global instance because after calling method has effect to all components where I use this service

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz to demonstrate your problem

Comment: Yes, 10 minutes I will do

Answer (score 0):

```
@Injectable()
export class XyzService{
    constructor(

  ) {
  }
}
```

use Injectable on top of the Service .